# How can I get the url of a profile on linkedin using the linkedin API

Tags: javascript, json, web, linkedin-api

So far, I can get the first and last name, email, positions, etc. but I can't find the command to get the url to the linkedin profile. I'm trying to send linkedin profile urls through my web app. Here is what I have for getting user data

```
 function grabUserData() {
    let profile = {};
  IN.API.Profile('me').fields([
    'first-name', 'last-name', // Add these to get the name
    'industry', 'date-of-birth', 'educations:(id,school-name)',
    'positions', // Add this one to get the job history
    'picture-url',//gets image
    'email-address'
  ]).result(function(profiles) {
    console.log(profiles.values[0]);//gives me profile info
    profile = profiles.values[0];
    updateWithInfo(profile);//just displays it on my site
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a field: `vanityName`.

The vanity name of the member. Vanity name is represented as a string is used for the public profile URL: www.linkedin.com/in/{vanityName}. [Basic Profile Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/profile/basic-profile)